# Result of time subtraction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I get a result of subtraction in words like "7 seconds"? `strftime` isn't working because the result is Fixnum.

```
a = Time.now
b = Time.now #a few seconds later

b - a
#7.17584 (seconds)
```

Comment: your expected output, should look like ?

Comment: Are you using Rails or Pure Ruby ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Rails, you can use [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words):

```
from_time = Time.now
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 15.seconds, include_seconds: true)
#less than 20 seconds
```

Comment: is it from Rails 4.1?

Comment: No, i've used in Rails 3. I'll search wich version it was specified

Comment: Just a reminder, you have to use #distance_of_time in words in your View.

Comment: This helper is to be foundon rails since 1.0.0 http://apidock.com/rails/v1.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words

Comment: I'm getting `undefined local variable or method `distance_of_time_in_words'`

Comment: Are you using in your view or in your controller?

Comment: I defined method in model and use it in view

Comment: You don't have to define the method in your model, just use in your view.

Answer (score 0):

For example as follows:

```
Time.at(Time.now - 7.seconds).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
# => "18:41:18"
```

and the difference between two times:

```
Time.at(Time.now - (Time.now - 7.seconds)).strftime("%1S.%5N (seconds)")
# 6.99998
```

Note: The instance method `-` returns the number of seconds between two times, `Time.at` returns a Time object constructed from an Integer, or Float, in seconds. The `%1S` format key for [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime) allows you to output the number of unpadded seconds.

Comment: it's great. but can you tell more about `%1S`? what if I need format like `2 hours 23 minutes`?

Comment: 1 mean that at least 1 char need to print the seconds value, if you omit it you will get: `06` seconds. See formant on method here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact needs, you can also write your own method, something like this:

```
def diff_time_in_words(first_time, second_time)
  (second_time - first_time).round(0).to_s + " seconds"
end
# nil
a = Time.now
# 2014-04-21 09:55:55 -0500
b = Time.now
# 2014-04-21 09:56:02 -0500
diff_time_in_words(a, b)
# "8 seconds"
```

Obviously, this assumes your result is always meant to be expressed in seconds, but it's a start.  If you're interested, I could go on.